# Stop Jinja2 Execution With IF Statement?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have some code like:

```
{% if key_var is not none %}
  {{ my_list[key_var] }}
{% endif %}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'None'
```

Is there a way to get Jinja2 to not run the code if the IF statement is false?  Or am I missing something else?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why not {% if key_var %} and leave it at that?

Comment: That snippet works for me on the latest Jinja2 (2.10). What version of Jinja2 are you using? And are you sure that that fragment is the culprit?

Comment: @dfundako Because zero would do the wrong thing

Comment: I'm using Jinja2 2.9.6.  I'll see if I can upgrade to 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if my_list[key_var] is defined %}
  {{ my_list[key_var] }}
{% endif %}
```

Got the behavior I was looking for.  I didn't want my_list[key_var] to run inside of the IF statement when the key_var is None

I don't know why this worked when my original attempt didn't.  If anyone knows, please fill me in.

Thank you!